# Cross-browser support for position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Is there a solid solution for implementing `position: fixed` that will be supported in all major browsers?

I was so proud of my recent code, that solved all my issues in FF, until I looked at it in IE. There seem to be a lot of hacks around but some of them seem to contradict each other...

I need to position several elements on a page relative to the window.

This code works great in FF, but not in IE, even v.9. The element is supposed to be fixed in the top-left corner even when I scroll the page. In IE it scrolls up with the page content.

```
#myElement{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
    height:35px;
    width:290px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    z-index: 999
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed), it's widely supported - can you be more specific about the problem you're having?

Comment: Post your html and css, the issue may not have anything to do with position fixed at all.  Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: There really shouldn't be a problem with `position:fixed`. Do you have a working example as well? Either a link or recreate the issue using http://jsfiddle.net. What `DOCTYPE` are you using? If I had to guess your page is being interpreted in Quirks mode due to invalid code.

Comment: @santa need to see the html too.

Comment: @tw16 Please see: http://www.usabilitest.com/uzvnbRC in FF first, then in IE. Thanks. You might be right about quirks mode. How do I debug that?

Comment: @Jrod pls see my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected, you are using an invalid `DOCTYPE` which is sending IE into *quirks* mode. To keep IE in *standards* mode you need to make sure you use a valid `DOCTYPE`. So, if you want to use HTML 4.01 transitional it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

However, I would use the shorter and simpler HTML5 `DOCTYPE`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I have added DOCTYPE, but i think my issue had something to do with FF upgrade. After I restarted it everything went back to normal...

Comment: @santa: I am fairly certain it wasn't the FF upgrade that messed up IE. Because I could see the problem too and I could see it being thrown into quirks mode by the invalid doctype.

Answer (score 2):

Only IE6 does not support `position:fixed`, and it's not major browser. (See browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed).)

Comment: what kind of issue? where is the code? we are not mediums. IE9 support fixed position

Answer (score 0):

Try using position:relative; or position:absolute; instead of position:fixed;
These are there in IE9.
However, many a times position property gives undesirable result, thus, I always prefer to avoid it as much as I can. Do check with Chrome/Webkit also.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone still has this problem.

Enter the following into your style sheet. All browsers will override position:absolute with position:fixed and you'll get what you want. IE 6 does not understand the > operator, so it never sees position:fixed and uses position:absolute. The web page is usable in all browsers, but not as pretty in IE6.

```
htmltag
    {position: absolute;}

body>htmltag
    {position:fixed;}
```